# Unity SDK, GetPersistentDataPath not supported on all platforms

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm developing a Playstation game with Unity3d that uses Parse. It seems that PS3 (and maybe others) don't support the application.persistenDataPath function. When I attempt to initialize parse, I see a file access exception when the system tries to load settings:

```
DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "//Parse.settings"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean anonymous, FileOptions options) [0x00000] in <filenam
e unknown>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean isAsync, Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in <filename un
known>:0
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.PlatformHooks+SettingsWrapper.Save () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.PlatformHooks+SettingsWrapper..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.PlatformHooks+SettingsWrapper.get_Wrapper () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.PlatformHooks.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.ParseClient.Initialize (System.String applicationId, System.String dotnetKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Parse.ParseInitializeBehaviour.Awake () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Is it possible to provide custom callbacks for reading/writing these settings?